# Create a new string by Concatenating the last letter of the given set of strings in Java

Tags: java

I need to get a number of words from user, and then output a final word which is formed by the concatenation of the last letters of the words that the user has input.

Here is the code. But how do I bring these letters from the loop and concatenate them?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class newWord {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("How many words are you going to enter?");
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = num.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please Enter the "+number+" words:");
        for(int n=1;n<=number;n++)
        {

            Scanner words = new Scanner(System.in);
            String thisword = words.nextLine();

            char str2 = thisword.charAt(thisword.length()-1);
            System.out.println(str2);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. Hint or code, I'm learning :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints only** ... since this is obviously a learning exercise of some kind.

> But how do I bring these letters from the loop and concatenate them?

You don't.  You concatenate them *within the loop*.

String concatenation can be done using the String `+` operator or `StringBuilder`.

The rest is up to you.  (Please ignore the dingbats who posted complete solutions and work it out for yourself.  It will do you good!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringBuilder` class to concatenate latest characters in strings with `append` method.

Answer (score 1):

I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) you are asking to take the last letter of each word and make that into one final word. All you need to do is take each of the final letters and add them to a String to hold them all. After the entire `for` loop, the variable `appended` should be your requested word.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.println("How many words are you going to enter?");
    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = num.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please Enter the "+number+" words:");
    String appended = ""; // Added this
    for(int n=1;n<=number;n++)
    {

        Scanner words = new Scanner(System.in);
        String thisword = words.nextLine();

        char str2 = thisword.charAt(thisword.length()-1);
        appended +=str2; // Added this
        System.out.println(str2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Great work (NOT!) ... now he doesn't need to do his homework.

Answer (score 1):

Just you miss things to keep final value in a place and finally print

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {

            System.out.println("How many words are you going to enter?");
            Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
            int number = num.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please Enter the "+number+" words:");
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for(int n=1;n<=number;n++)
            {

                Scanner words = new Scanner(System.in);
                String thisword = words.nextLine();

                char str2 = thisword.charAt(thisword.length()-1);
                sb.append(str2);

            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());

        }
```

Comment: Great work (NOT!) ... now he doesn't need to do his homework.

Answer (score 1):

go through [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) classes you will get your answer..